# Custom salt generator in BCryptPasswordEncoder

Tags: spring-security

I know that the salt we use to encrypt passwords should be :

> - They are algorithmically generated from some pieces of data associated with the user, for example, the timestamp that the user
>     created
> - They are randomly generated and stored in some form
> - They are plaintext or two-way encrypted along with the user's password record

Due to the first point, when anyone access to db, set his password for another user, he can not login instead of another user. 
but when I use BCryptPasswordEncoder I replace my password in password column of another user and I can login by that user.

**In my opinion, it is a security problem**, because the admin that access to database can login instead of any user and may do some work. and these works is logged by that user not admin user.

**If we use `userId` or `userCreationTime` or something like that to generate salt and override 
`PasswordEncoder#match` method, the problem is resolved.**

If these points are true my question is:
How can I use a custom salt generator in BCryptPasswordEncoder?

Comment: Password salts protect against dictionary attacks (aka pre-computed hash attack). They do not provide protection against malicious administrators and were never meant to be.

Comment: And a clever malicious administrator can compute a valid hashed password himself. He/she has access to the required ingredients (`userId`, `userCreationTime` etc.). So the proposed approach will raise the bar for a hack slighlty but will not prevent it in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salting is meant to prevent [rainbow table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attacks against leaked hashed passwords.  With good per-user salting, one rainbow table will not work for the entire db, and an attacker needs to generate a rainbow table per user.  This, combined with a computationally complex hashing algo, makes impractical to reverse engineer passwords from a leaked hashed password db.

If someone can manipulate the db, however, you are pwnz0r3d.  If an admin can modify the db, they can modify user creation time.  They can also "swap" user id with the known value.